# Transfer Excel files to a database server directory path in APEX

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently using APEX 5.1. I have a file browse item in my page. And an upload button.

When the user selects a file and clicks on upload button, the file has to be transferred to a directory path(directory path created).

I'm able to transfer `.txt` files using blob to clob conversions and `UTL_FILE` packages. But when I do the same with `.xls` or `.xlsx` files, the data is getting transferred in an unreadable pattern.

How can I transfer excel file to DB server directory path using PL/SQL or JavaScript in APEX? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't copying Excel files but images; everything went fine. I was using WWV_FLOW_FILES table; you'd, probably, use your own table, store XLS into its BLOB column, and then use this procedure (code follows), read BLOB and UTL_FILE it into a directory specified by the P_DIR parameter.

```
   PROCEDURE p_write_blob_to_file (p_file_id IN NUMBER, p_dir IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      /* 19.04.2012. Procedure copies image from WWV_FLOW_FILES into a
                     directory P_DIR. Taken from Eddie Awad's Blog
                     http://awads.net/wp/2011/09/20/create-an-application-to-upload-files-using-oracle-apex-in-less-than-10-minutes-video/
      */
      l_blob            BLOB;
      l_blob_length     INTEGER;
      l_out_file        UTL_FILE.file_type;
      l_buffer          RAW (32767);
      l_chunk_size      BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
      l_blob_position   INTEGER := 1;
      l_file_name       pkg_general.subt_ime_slike;
   BEGIN
      -- Retrieve the BLOB for reading
      SELECT blob_content, filename
        INTO l_blob, l_file_name
        FROM wwv_flow_files
       WHERE id = p_file_id;

      -- Retrieve the SIZE of the BLOB
      l_blob_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_blob);

      -- Open a handle to the location where you are going to write the BLOB
      -- to file.
      -- NOTE: The 'wb' parameter means "write in byte mode" and is only
      --       available in the UTL_FILE package with Oracle 10g or later
      l_out_file :=
         UTL_FILE.fopen (p_dir,
                         l_file_name,
                         'wb' -- important. If ony w then extra carriage return/line brake
                             ,
                         l_chunk_size);

      -- Write the BLOB to file in chunks
      WHILE l_blob_position <= l_blob_length
      LOOP
         IF l_blob_position + l_chunk_size - 1 > l_blob_length
         THEN
            l_chunk_size := l_blob_length - l_blob_position + 1;
         END IF;

         DBMS_LOB.read (l_blob,
                        l_chunk_size,
                        l_blob_position,
                        l_buffer);
         UTL_FILE.put_raw (l_out_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
         l_blob_position := l_blob_position + l_chunk_size;
      END LOOP;

      -- Close the file handle
      UTL_FILE.fclose (l_out_file);
   END p_write_blob_to_file;
```